# How to make a newly inserted <tr> tag to occupy the total width of the table

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a table and I am inserting a new row dynamically. It contains only on td. But it is occupying only one td width as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WAuw4/3/)
How can i make newly inserted tr to occupy the total width of the table.

```
 Here number of td s are not fixed.That is, it is not always 3.
```

Here is my HTML

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr id='a'><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is my code

```
$('<tr id="b" style="background-color:blue"><td >new</td></tr>').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

Else here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WAuw4/3/) to put hands on..

Comment: Add the same amount of `<td>`s as the rest of the table or use a colspan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `colspan` to the `<td>` element:

```
$('<tr id="b" style="background-color:blue"><td colspan="3">new</td></tr>').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WAuw4/5/

**EDIT**

If you don't know the number of cells in the table:

```
var colspan = $('#a td').length;
$('<tr id="b" style="background-color:blue"><td colspan="' + colspan + '">new</td></tr>').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

Comment: Yes you answer is perfect... But number of <td> s is not always fixed.

Comment: I've just update the answer to get the number of cells in the row you're inserting before, and using that as the number of columns

Answer (score 2):

```
total_td = $('table tr:first td').length;

$('<tr id="b" style="background-color:blue"><td colspan="' + total_td  + '">new</td></tr>').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

Comment: Yes you answer is perfect... But number of <td> s is not always fixed.

Comment: answer updated. you have to see which row has max TDs, give that an ID and use that to get 'total_td', hope you understand....

Answer (score 2):

You could add `colspan=3` in your new `td`

```
$('<tr id="b" style="background-color:blue"><td colspan=3>new</td></tr>').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/WAuw4/4/

Here's a bit more on the `colspan` attribute: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/td/colspan

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment

> But number of `<td>` s is not always fixed.

I would do this

Check the number of `td` in the first row.  Add that to your `colspan`

```
var len = $('tr:first td').length;

$('<tr id="b" style="background-color:blue"><td colspan=' + len + '>new</td></tr>').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WAuw4/7/

Comment: Yes you answer is perfect... But number of <td> s is not always fixed.

Answer (score 0):

insert `colspan="3"` like this

```
$('<tr id="b" style="background-color:blue"><td colspan="3">new</td></tr>').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Colspan` to adjust the span of the td in the row.

```
$('<tr id="b" style="background-color:blue"><td `colspan="3"` >new</td></tr>').insertBefore($('#a'));
```

I have checked on you jsfiddle..

you should have some fixed or predictable count of `<td>` else how can you manage this.. if you want to implement such approach then on the place of `<td>` use `<div>`